# Another class of animals is/are fish

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I came across this sentence in an elementary grammar book:

> **Another class of animals is fish.** Scientists believe there are more than 24,000 kinds of fish. Fish live in the water and come in many shapes and sizes. They have scales, fins, and gills. Most are cold-blooded.

Shouldn’t this be written "Another class of animals **are** fish" ? 
Using “is” doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: How many classes of animals are mentioned in the sentence?

Comment: Here is the complete paragraph given.

Comment: Another class of animals is fish. Scientists believe there are more than 24,000 kinds of fish. Fish live in the water and come in many shapes and sizes. They have scales, fins, and gills. Most are cold-blooded.

Comment: There is only one class (of animals) mentioned, so the subject of the sentence (another class of animals) is singular. This means that it is correct to use ***is***.

Comment: @Mick You mean to say that with more than one class you'd still use **another** but with a plural verb?

Comment: @SovereignSun No. I would use "Other classes of animals are fish and reptiles."

Answer (score 1):

"**another**" is always singular. Here the verb corresponds with "**another**" and not with "**fish**".

- Another *[class of animals]* **is** fish.

But if you revert the noun order then either "*is*" or "*are*" would be correct depending on how you render the word "**fish**":

- Fish *is/are* another class of animals.

However, to talk about classification the singular is prefered.

Comment: I also think you should say "**another class of animal**" in respect to grammar rules concerning "**type of, class of, kind of, etc**"

Answer (score 1):

In "*Another class of animals is fish.*", ***is*** is correct. The subject noun is *class*, which is singular. This is also shown in the use of *another*, with the *an-* prefix being the singular indefinite article. If the topic of animal groups or classes were already known from preceding sentences, it could also be written as:

> Another class is fish.

Here it is clearer that we are discussing the class, which is clearly written in the singular form. What may be a little confusing is that fish is written the same for both the singular and plural forms. If another group were chosen, for example:

> Another class is reptiles.

*Reptiles* is clearly written in the plural form and with some repetition we can construct the picture that the starting phrase is *Another class is ...*

So in this sentence, ***is*** is correct, but how it should be written is:

> Another class of animal is fish.

*Animal* should be singular. Just as if they had written *Another type of reptile is ...* You can test this by replacing *class* with a synonym: "Another *type* of animal is fish." and then inverting the sentence to form a question: "Is fish another type of animal?" Here you can see that, "Is fish another type of animals?"  isn't right.

Just as a point of interest, *fish* are not, scientifically speaking, a class of animal, but belong to one of three classes:

- Class Agnatha (jawless fish)
- Class Chondrichthyes (cartilaginous fish)
- Class Osteichthyes (bony fish)